# Does SQL server generate an execution plan every time when querying data with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-execution-plan

I know that EF does some caching of execution plans on application level, but I am interested to know if SQL server generates an execution plan on each request.
Is there any preference that I can enable to make SQL cache execution plans for any queries, not only for store procedures.

Comment: The tool that creates the SQL query doesn't matter at all as far as execution plans and caching is concerned - EF, NH, or writing by hand. Neither does the *client* - SSMS, your own app or sqcli.

Comment: No, EF doesn't do any kind of execution plan caching. It doesn't know anything about execution plans, that's a database engine concept that EF, or any ORM, knows nothing about. It's the *database* that generates and caches execution plans

Comment: And finally, execution plan caching works for *all* queries, whether they are contained in a stored procedure or not. The next time you send the same query, SQL Server will look into its execution plan cache for a matching execution plan and reuse it

Comment: What is your *actual* question? Have you encountered an EF performance problem and think that execution plan caching is the cause? It may be, but no due to any of the assumptions in the question. A far more likely culprit would be missing indexes or bad queries.

Comment: Complex queries can result in bad execution plans and bad performance. Quite often complex queries are used because the *database schema* isn't suitable for the job at hand - using an OLTP database for reporting will always result in problems simply because the database design isn't suitable for reporting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,my problem actually is so: we are now working on SP approach and all queries made by corresponding SP. Now we want to move to EF code first approach and get rid of SP at all. Our DBA say that when we use SP db server caches the plan, but if we use EF - db server will generate new execution plan for every request. So I need to get proofs that DBA is wrong.

Comment: What's wrong, is the blanket assumption that you can move to EF. EF is an *ORM*, not a SQL replacement. It's meant to Map Objects to Relational tables.  If you *don't* use proper relations, if you *aren't* careful and check what kind of SQL is produced by LINQ queries, you may end up with unmanagable code, overly complex queries and bad performance that no DBA will be able to fix

Comment: There won't be any performance difference if you execute a simple SELECT through the ORM or a stored procedure. You may get *better* performance if LINQ queries replace catch-all WHERE statements. ORMs and LINQ can't simplify complex stored procedures though, nor can they update rows directly *without* loading an object first. That can cause a lot of trouble

Comment: The DBA is *right* to worry a *little* about the query plan cache too. An ORM produces ad-hoc queries which means that each query may need its own execution plan. This shouldn't be a real worry though, unless people start to load big object graphs, or try to use JOINs in LINQ instead of creating proper relations between entities.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand everything, and that EF is ORM and that ORM produces queries and we need to worry about optimization on the code level. So basically we need to follow best practices when using ORM queries, to avoid performance issues. I was just looking for proofs that SQL server will not produce new execution plan for same queries when running multiple times.

Comment: in that case I'd suggest moving from `find proof` to `How can we do this correctly`. Following "best practices" seldom works. One has to understand what the actual issues are, what the advice fixes and when it *doesn't* apply. Yes, query cache explosion is a valid concern when an application can generate ad-hoc queries. Yes, query optimization becomes a *lot* harder when you don't have access to the SQL text, or when that query is generated indirectly from an ORM

Comment: Log queries in EF so you can see what's actually going on. *Do* use Query Store for the same reason, to find any "bad' queries and check for regressions. It's all too easy to get into a bad spot without realizing it. Profile as much as possible. In fact, if you target ASP.NET, use MiniProfiler so developers can *always* see how fast/slow queries are in *all* web pages. You may be surprised by how many queries run one after another when loading the data to fill a page, stuff that should be loaded in one go

Comment: *Antipatterns* like "Generic Repository" can eradicate performance and result in N queries when only 1 is needed. Repositories for single entities made sense *before* ORMs like EF and languages like LINQ came about. Nowadays, most repository methods are just aliases for DbSet calls in the best case. In the worst case they force you to load big objects when you only want 1 field, or load objects one by one when you could retrieve all of them at once

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server caches every plan (not only for procedures) that it generates in memory. These plans might not be long there. Basically, it depends on how busy is your server, how much RAM do you have, how SQL server is pressed for memory etc. Alternatively, you can enable query store, but it is a new feature that was introduced in SQL server 2016. There are a few options, but i.e. it is able to save for you plans for specific queries and a history of executions etc. You can use this query to see what's actually in your cache:

```
SELECT 
     c.usecounts
    ,c.size_in_bytes
    ,c.objtype
    ,query.text
    ,plans.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS c
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS query
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS plans
ORDER BY c.usecounts DESC
```